# should reassigning my viewmodel clear ui data in <tbody data-bind="foreach: Propertys">

Tags: knockout.js

I have some html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Propertys">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Postcode">                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='#/value: ID'>View</a>

                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: '#/property/' + ID() }">Report</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I have a view model obviously with a observable Propertys.

This is on a spa, the code to load my dashboard is:

```
function load(propertyID) {
        //we need to call data.property.load
        //get that data back and assign it to the view model.

        //get our dashboard data and bind to ui
        data.property.load(propertyID, function (result) {
            ko.applyBindings(new propertyModel(result),$('#propertyView')[0]);

            presenter.switchView('propertyView');

            toastr.success('Property Successfully Loaded', 'Successfully Loaded');
        }, function () {
            toastr.error('Error occured', 'Oh no');
        });
    }
```

I have different "views" on my page but when I go off to one and then come back to my dashboard which is the html you see above, I re-grab the data to display and although I'm doing this again:

```
ko.applyBindings(new propertyModel(result),$('#propertyView')[0]);
```

The data in my :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Propertys">
```

is duplicating.

I'm new to knockout js, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell without knowing what your presenter is doing, but in general you will want to avoid calling `ko.applyBindings` on content that has already been bound.

If you are trying to load a new `propertyModel` into your view, then it generally helps to use either the `with` or `template` binding against an observable like:

```
<div data-bind="with: currentPropertyModel">
   ...content here
</div>
```

Then, you define a `currentPropertyModel` as an observable, call applyBindings a single time, and then just set and clear `currentPropertyModel` with the model that you want rendered. When you clear it, the content will be removed and when you set it to a new one, then it will be rendered with that new model as the context.